# How to replace WireMock @Rule annotation in JUnit 5?

Tags: java, junit5, wiremock, junit-rule

I'm using WireMock in my tests and have such a line of code:

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(8080);
```

I want to switch to JUnit 5. So I added the next dependency (using Gradle):

```
testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.1')
```

But there are no suggestions when I'm trying to import `@Rule` annotation.

Do I need to add another module of JUnit dependency? Or are rules not supported in JUnit 5? If not, how can I replace `@Rule` annotation to make tests work again?

Comment: Check this nice article https://www.codeaffine.com/2016/04/06/replace-rules-in-junit5/

Comment: There is no direct replacement, Junit Jupiter uses `@Extension` rather than `@Rlue`; developers need to port their code - WireMock haven't [done this yes](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/684). You can implement an `@Extension` yourself.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In a general way, what you did with `@Rule` and `@ClassRule` in JUnit 4 should be done with [`@ExtendWith`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.3/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExtendWith.html) and [`Extension`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.3/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/Extension.html) that associated provide a very close feature in JUnit 5.
It works as standards JUnit lifecycle hooks but that it is extracted in a `Extension` class. And similarly to `@Rule`, as many `Extension`s as required may be added for a test class.

To handle the issue you have several possible approaches among :

- keep the JUnit 4 way (JUnit 5 owns the JUnit Vintage part that allows to execute JUnit 3 or 4 tests).
- rewrite the `@Rule` as an `Extension`.
- do the actual processing done by `WireMockRule` (start the server, execute your tests and stop the server) in each test of class with `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` hook methods.
- use a third library that implements the equivalent of WireMockRule in the JUnit 5 Extension way such as https://github.com/lanwen/wiremock-junit5

Note that your issue already discussed in [the JUnit 5 Issues](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/684).

Comment: For a shortcut on making the extension see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66060677/1355930

Answer (score 14):

JUnit 4 annotations `@Rule` and `@ClassRule` do not exist in JUnit 5. Basically there is a new extension model that can be used to implement extensions with the same functionality. These extensions can be used with the `@ExtendWith` annotation.

There is a limited migration support for a subset of JUnit 4 rules in the *junit-jupiter-migrationsupport* module. Unfortunately, it's only limited to subclasses of `ExternalResource` and `Verifier`.

Before wiremock has official support for JUnit you have some workarounds:

1. Run JUnit 4 tests side by side with JUnit 5 tests with the *junit-vintage-engine*.
2. Start and stop the server yourself in the test code.
3. Use a 3rd party extension like [wiremock-junit5](https://github.com/lanwen/wiremock-junit5) or [wiremock-extension](https://github.com/JensPiegsa/wiremock-extension).

Answer (score 7):

There is now official support for JUnit 5 Jupiter from WireMock 2.31.0.

Docs here: http://wiremock.org/docs/junit-jupiter/

Comment: Great! Though I still wonder if injecting `WireMockRuntimeInfo` is the only way to get the assigned port (other than specifying a static port manually). My test methods already have long names. With `WireMockRuntimeInfo`, the signature is a mile long

Comment: Oh, I can inject it in `@BeforeEach` and make `port` a field...

Answer (score 1):

From the [JUnit 5 user guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips):

> `@Rule` and `@ClassRule` no longer exist; superseded by `@ExtendWith` and `@RegisterExtension`. See also ["Limited JUnit 4 Rule Support"](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-rule-support).

However, as [pointed out by Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69117443/3429133), WireMock has full JUnit Jupiter support since version 2.31.0:

```java
// New JUnit 5 extension
@WireMockTest
class DeclarativeWireMockTest {

    @Test
    void test_something_with_wiremock(WireMockRuntimeInfo wmRuntimeInfo) {
        // The static DSL will be automatically configured for you
        stubFor(get("/static-dsl").willReturn(ok()));
      
        // Instance DSL can be obtained from the runtime info parameter
        WireMock wireMock = wmRuntimeInfo.getWireMock();
        wireMock.register(get("/instance-dsl").willReturn(ok()));
       
        // Info such as port numbers is also available
        int port = wmRuntimeInfo.getHttpPort();
        
        // Do some testing...
    }

}
```

For more information, please refer to the [corresponding docs](http://wiremock.org/docs/junit-jupiter/).

Answer (score 0):

The https://github.com/webcompere/java-test-gadgets project lets you solve this in a couple of ways.

You can use its support for JUnit 4 rules via the `DangerousRuleAdapter` - which will attempt to turn any JUnit 4 rule into a `Plugin`:

```java
@ExtendWith(PluginExtension.class)
public class DangerousRuleAdapterExampleTest {
    @Plugin
    private DangerousRuleAdapter<WireMockRule> adapter = 
        new DangerousRuleAdapter<>(new WireMockRule());

    @Test
    void theTest() {
        // use wiremock rule here
        WireMockRule rule = adapter.get();
    }
```

The rule adapters cannot work with rules that inspect the test class or the test method, but make a good attempt at running the rule.

There's also support for running a rule around some code:

```java
    TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    // let's use this temp folder with some test code
    executeWithRule(temporaryFolder, () -> {
        // here, the rule is _active_
        callSomethingThatUses(temporaryFolder.getRoot());
    });
```

And you can easily create your own new JUnit 5 plugin by using the `PluginExtension` and `TestResource.of`

```java
@ExtendWith(PluginExtension.class)
class TestResourceIsActiveDuringTest {
    private WireMockServer server;

    @Plugin
    private TestResource someResource = TestResource.from(() -> server.start(),
                                                          () -> server.stop());
```

Comment: `DangerousRule...`? LOL. Crazy name choice :).

Comment: @DutA. I wanted a name that gave people a sense of why it might not always work ;)