# How can I migrate a @Rule of Testname from junit4 to the TestInfo in Junit 5 from an abstract java class?

Tags: java, testing, junit4, junit5

In my Abstract class I have this code line :

```
@Rule
  public final TestName testName = new TestName();
```

That is used in some tests to pass the specific method the name, for example:

```
@Test
public void assertApiUp() {
    sendTest(testName.getMethodName(),true);
}
```

How do you manage this in junit 5 with TestInfo? I was thinking add in my set up method
@BeforeEach
void setUp(TestContext context, TestInfo testInfo){deploy(context,testInfo)}

or do you think is better in each testClass, for instance:

```
 @Test
  @DisplayName("assertApiUp")
  public void assertApiUp(TestInfo testInfo) {...}
```

And another doubt, how do you put this other piece of code in junit 5 :

```
 @Rule
    public TestRule doOnfail = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    protected void failed(Description desc) {
     stopAllRunningContainers();
    }
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51012642/3287786.

Comment: The best way depends on what you want to do with the test name. So what is your intention?

Comment: Thanks @johanneslink, I've edit a bit more my question, but as I've mentionated there,it's an abstract test class,then you can imagine that it's to use a common behavior features in the tests.