# Not able to use @Rule & @RunWith annotation, but the deprecated initmocks() works

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, junit5

I am working on a basic test-driven development learning of a simple java program which provides portfolio value for the stocks.

I am having 2 classes,`Portfolio.java` & `Stock.java` which depicts the portfolio & stock models. An interface `StockService.java` is used in abstract manner to get real-time stock price.

`PortfolioTest.java` is the class in which I am trying to write unit-tests for the features of portfolio by mocking this StockService using Mockito.

I am able to use the deprecated `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` & run my tests but getting null pointer exception if try to use `@Rule` or `@RunWith` annotations.

`Stock.java`

```java
public class Stock {
    private String name;
    private int quantity;

    public Stock(String name, int quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public float getQuantity() { return quantity; }
}
```

`Portfolio.java`

```java
import java.util.List;

public class Portfolio {
    private List<Stock> stocks;
    private StockService stockService;
    private Float portfolioValue;

    public Portfolio(List<Stock> stocks, Float portfolioValue) {
        this.stocks = stocks;
        this.portfolioValue = portfolioValue;
    }

    public void setStockService(StockService stockService) { this.stockService = stockService; }

    public Float calculateMarketValue() {
        Float marketValue = 0.0f;
        for(Stock stock: this.stocks) {
            marketValue += (stock.getQuantity()*stockService.getRealtimePrice(stock.getName()));
        }
        return marketValue;
    }

    public Boolean isInProfit() {
        return (portfolioValue<calculateMarketValue()?true:false);
    }
}
```

`StockService.java`

```java
public interface StockService {
    public float getRealtimePrice(String name);
}
```

`pom.xml`

```xml
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>mockito-basic</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`PortfolioTest.java`

```java
//@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PortfolioTestMockAnnotations {

    //@Rule public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Mock
    StockService stockService;

    @InjectMocks
    Portfolio portfolio;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() {

    }

    @BeforeEach
    void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        System.out.println(stockService);
        when(stockService.getRealtimePrice("infosys")).thenReturn(2200.0f);
        when(stockService.getRealtimePrice("reliance")).thenReturn(3100.0f);
        when(stockService.getRealtimePrice("indiamart")).thenReturn(4000.0f);

        List<Stock> stocks = new ArrayList<>();
        stocks.add(new Stock("infosys",10));
        stocks.add(new Stock("reliance", 5));
        portfolio = new Portfolio(stocks, 35000.0f);
        portfolio.setStockService(stockService);
    }

    @Test
    public void calculateMarketValueTest() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(portfolio.calculateMarketValue(),37500);
    }

    @Test
    public void calculateIsInProfitTest() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(portfolio.isInProfit());
    }
}
```

---

**Using initmocks()** in the PortfolioTest.java runs the test smoothly.
[image]

---

**Using @Rule**, throws NPE
[image]

---

**Using @RunWith**, throws NPE
[image]

---

Please suggest the correct way for using @Rule & @RunWith in a smooth. Also provide brief difference between these 3 mechanisms of instantiating mocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your POM reveals that you might somehow mix JUnit5 and JUnit4. There are two annotations to declare method as test:

```
@org.junit.Test // for JUnit4
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test // for JUnit5
```

If you annotate for **JUnit4** and run test as JUnit4 test everything should be fine.

But if you annotate with JUnit5 and run as JUnit5 test things will be a bit different. JUnit5 does not use `@Rule` nor `@RunWith` but has its own way to initialize mocks. [Article](https://mincong.io/2020/04/19/mockito-junit5/) which might explain why something works and something not.

In a nutshell, for running as JUnit5 your class should have annotation:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

because `@Rule` or `RunWith` does not work anymore. This annotation needs dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I run only JUnit5 and have these dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51012335/6413377)

Answer (score 0):

In Junit5, @RunsWith() is replaced with @ExtendWith({MockitoExtension.class}), where MockitoExntension is coming from

```
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
         <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
         <version>3.11.2</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
```

3.11.2 is the current version at the time I am posting the solution. For more info you can visit: [Mockito and Junit5](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-junit-5-extension)