# Junit5: Equivalent of @Rule and Expect

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

I have some code which I have written in old version of jUnit. Now I am trying to migrate.

How to write this in Junit5?

```
 @Test
  public void testSignatureFailureRuntimeException() throws Exception {
    thrown.expect(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.class);
    HmacUtil hmacUtil = new HmacUtil(HmacUtil.SignatureAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA1, "");
  }
```

```
  @Test
  public void testDeploymentInfoWithEmptyConfig() {
    thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
    deploymentId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    FunctionDeploymentInfo.FunctionDeploymentInfoBuilder builder = FunctionDeploymentInfo.builder();
    FunctionDeploymentInfo fdi = builder
      .withDeploymentId(deploymentId)
      .withFulfilledBy(this.getClass().getName())
      .forPodTag(MicrodoseConstants.ONE_DATA)
      .withConfig(new JsonObject())
      .build();

    LocalMap<String, FunctionDeploymentInfo> deploymentInfo = vertx.sharedData().getLocalMap(deploymentInfoKey);
    deploymentInfo.clear();
    LocalMap<String, String> addressIndex = vertx.sharedData().getLocalMap(addressIndexKey);
    addressIndex.clear();

    fdi.registerDeploymentInfo(addressIndex, deploymentInfo);
  }
```

And another is @Rule

```
@ExtendWith(VertxExtension.class)
public class FunctionDeploymentInfoTest {

  @Rule
  public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the first one you can try:

```
    Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> new HmacUtil(HmacUtil.SignatureAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA1, ""));
```

With the second one maybe this will help you:
[How to replace WireMock @Rule annotation in JUnit 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51012335/how-to-replace-wiremock-rule-annotation-in-junit-5#:%7E:text=JUnit%204%20annotations%20%40Rule%20and,used%20with%20the%20%40ExtendWith%20annotation.)

Comment: Hi Can you also please look into another method testDeploymentInfoWithEmptyConfig?

Comment: @Piku Just put the code, which should throw the exception within the lamda-expression in JUnit5. 
`Assertions.assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> // Put your code here );`. 
So in your case I think it would be: `Assertions.assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> fdi.registerDeploymentInfo(addressIndex, deploymentInfo));`. <br>
I would also appreciate an accepted answer if it helped :)

Comment: After .build(); it is throwing null pointer exception, I just debugged

Comment: I accepted the answer as one of your solution worked for me. Can you also please try to help me on second one

Comment: @Piku Do you mean with the second one the testDeploymentInfoWithEmptyConfig or the @Rule? 
When .build() is throwing the exception, you can try: `Assertions.assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> builder.withDeploymentId(deploymentId).withFulfilledBy(this.getClass().getName()).forPodTag(MicrodoseConstants.ONE_DATA).withConfig(new JsonObject()).build());`

Sry in comments it is really bad to format