# How to replace @Rule in JUNIT5

Tags: java, junit5

I want to convert this piece of code in JUNIT 5 without using @Rule. I tried JUINT 5 TestWatcher but it doens't have starting method.
tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51012335/how-to-replace-wiremock-rule-annotation-in-junit-5)  but not able to understand how to implement ExtendWith or Extension

```
 @Rule
    public TestWatcher watchman = new TestWatcher() {
    
        @Override
        public void starting(final Description description) {
            logger.info("STARTING test: " + description.getMethodName());
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For more information about JUnit 5, I suggest reading the [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/).

---

In JUnit 5, if you want to execute a method before each test, then you can use the [`@BeforeEach`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeEach.html) annotation. To get information about the test to be executed you can give the method a [`TestInfo`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInfo.html) parameter which will be automatically injected for you. For example:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInfo;
// import logger...

class XXXTests {

  final Logger logger = ...;

  @BeforeEach
  void logStartOfTest(TestInfo info) {
    logger.info("STARTING test: " + info.getMethod().map(Method::getName).orElse(null));
  }

  @Test
  void testFoo() {
    // perform assertions
  }
}
```

If you don't want to have to write that for every test, then you can create your own extension that implements [`BeforeEachCallback`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/BeforeEachCallback.html). For example:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeEachCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
// import logger..

public class MyExtension implements BeforeEachCallback {

    final Logger logger = ...;

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        logger.info("STARTING test: " + context.getTestMethod().map(Method::getName).orElse(null));
    }
}
```

Then apply your extension:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
class XXXTests {

    @Test
    void testFoo() {
        // perform assertions
    }
}
```

Your extension class can implement multiple extension interfaces. If you want to watch for success and failure, then you can also implement [`org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestWatcher`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestWatcher.html), but note that interface only became stable API in JUnit 5.7 (I believe it was added in version 5.4).

Answer (score 1):

Junit 5 has its own definition of an interface called `TestWatcher` – see [User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-test-result-processing) – but it doesn't have a method equivalent to JUnit 4's `starting` method. Instead, what you had in the `starting` method in JUnit 4 can go into the `@BeforeEach` method of JUnit 5, and for the remaining methods (such as those handling test success and failure) you can implement this interface and override its methods (such as `testSuccessful` and `testFailed`) and then use your extension class with the @ExtendWith annotation like this:

```
@ExtendWith(MyTestWatcher.class)
class MyTestClass {
    ...
}
```